# How can add/edit my php.ini t define my own parameters

Tags: php, cpanel

How can **add/edit** my php.ini t define my own parameters? In cpanel on a shared **server.php** server in that case.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and share some of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I got a good approach that can work on any server. I will give my scenario, you can change based on your environment.

1.create .htacess file  in the public_html and paste this

```
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value max_input_vars 10000
   php_value memory_limit 8000M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
   always_populate_raw_post_data=-1 
</IfModule>
```

2. create user.ini file  in the public_html and paste this

```
   asp_tags = Off
    display_errors = On
    max_execution_time = 300
    max_input_time = 600
    max_input_vars = 10000
    memory_limit = 8000M
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
    session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
    upload_max_filesize = 1000M
    always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
```

3. create php.ini file  in the public_html and paste this

   ```
   allow_url_fopen = On
   allow_url_include = Off
   asp_tags = Off
   display_errors = On
   enable_dl = On
   file_uploads = On
   max_execution_time = 300
   max_input_time = 600
   max_input_vars = 10000
   memory_limit = 8000M
   session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
   session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   upload_max_filesize = 1000M
   always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
   ```

Done!!!!!!!! It worked for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

## Edit your `php.ini`

You really need WHM access – not cPanel (or extraneous, vulnerable hacks).

### Are you here because of another installer?

For example, whilst experimenting with ways to approach the [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) install, I recommend NOT using the standard installer. It may throw `"always_populate_raw_post_data = -1"`, as it did for me.

If you're without WHM access, try [Softaculous](https://www.softaculous.com/).

> Save time by updating to at least php7.1

Matomo will be and running **really** quickly if that is why you need to edit `php.ini`.